# Why is Delphi TTreeNodes fundamentally tied to TCustomTreeView?

Tags: delphi, tree, c++builder, ttreenodes

I'm trying to build several 'trees' in memory, and later assign one of them to a TTreeView control that the user can interact with. However, I can't construct any TTreeNodes objects without passing a pointer to an existing TTreeView. Passing in NIL causes AVs.

Two questions:- What's the reason for this "hard" linking between TTreeNodes and TTreeViews, **and**, what's the best way of solving the problem?

Some options I can see are:

- Maintaining my own tree structure
  without ttreenodes and dynamically
  building the TTreeNodes as required.
- Having multiple invisible TTreeView
  objects that are just used to make
  the TTreeNodes stuff work.

.. but I haven't weighed up pros and cons for these.

Comment: I've rolled back the tag change. This isn't a question about generic tree nodes, but *specifically* about the behaviour of  the delphi "TTreeNodes" class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of code in `TTreeView` and its related classes to keep the link between the Delphi objects and the underlying Windows control in sync. When nodes are added directly via window messages, the Delphi object needs to reflect that change the very next time you ask it how many nodes it has, for example.

`TTreeView` is a wrapper for the Windows control, and `TTreeNodes` and `TTreeNode` are simply part of that wrapper. They don't actually implement all the tree operations that the control does. Certain operations are invalid if there currently isn't any Windows control available.

`TTreeView` is a visual control. If you don't have anything to visualize, then it's not the control for you. If you have multiple tree data structures, and you only want one tree control, then you're going to have to live with destroying and re-creating the tree nodes whenever you switch to a different structure. The control doesn't even provide a way to hide certain nodes temporarily.

You might be interested in [Mike Lischke's virtual tree control](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=33). In its intended usage, you manage the tree data structure yourself; the control is *just* a visualization. It asks you how many children each node has, and then it asks you what the text of each node is each time it has to draw that node. It managed which nodes are expanded, selected, checked, or visible, but you manage all the data. It is [free and open-source](http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/).

Comment: +1 for Virtual Tree View component. Try it, learn it, love it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source of TTreeNodes, you see that it requires the Owner (which is a TCustomTreeView). You can use a hidden treeview or create a custom subclass.

I prefer to separate gui from datamodel. So there is always a datamodel with the correct relations.

Comment: Owner is usually optional, but in this case not, which is more or less the question.

Comment: Owner is accessed without a check for nil. So in this case it is not optional.

Answer (score 2):

The (main) reason would likely be to prevent you from having a TTreeNode appear in more than 1 TTreeview. It is a common design pattern, also found in XmlNode classes etc.

As for your 2 options, hard to say without knowing more about the what/how/how many in your project.

If there are the slightest differences in appearance/behavior associated with the Node sets I would go for swapping TTreeviews.